# Packages/dll required for creating web method in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I want to create Web Method in C# which I should be able to call from javascript. I want to know what all packages/dll I need to install for creating web methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asp.net web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [wcf restful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide)

[Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework for building web APIs on top of the
>   .NET Framework. In this tutorial, you will use ASP.NET Web API to
>   create a web API that returns a list of products. The front-end web
>   page uses jQuery to display the results.

[WCF Restful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide)

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is an SDK for developing and
>   deploying services on Windows. WCF provides a runtime environment for
>   your services, enabling you to expose CLR types as services, and to
>   consume other services as CLR types.

Answer (score -1):

You need System.Web.Services.dll

Comment: @Nimmi I have found this dll from dlldll.com but I do not know how to proceed /use/install it. Readme file does not contain any instruction regarding this

Comment: You should include more details to support your answer! otherwise it looks like either "not an answer" or "low quality answer"